# open pdf file selected in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have all the dirctories (2014, 2012), the files of each selected folder (.pdf) in the listbox 2

[image: dirctories (2012,2013) and files (pdf)]

I get the dirctories by this code

```
if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    DirectoryInfo[] diri_info = newDirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath).GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diri in diri_info)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(diri);
    }
```

and i get the files by this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirictory_choisis = (DirectoryInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        FileInfo[] files = dirictory_choisis.GetFiles();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("selectioner un dossier");
    }

}
```

Now how I can open the selected file (.pdf)  ?

i use this code but dosn't work ( throw an exception file dosn't found)

```
private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{      
    FileInfo file = (FileInfo) listBox2.SelectedItem;  
    Process.Start(file.Name);            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code: "newDirectoryInfo"

By the way, file.Name only returns the name (not including path). You should replace that line with:

```
Process.Start(file.FullName);
```

So the listBox2_Click should be like this:

```
private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo file = (FileInfo)listBox2.SelectedItem;
        Process.Start(file.FullName);
    }
```

Comment: I could not identify it (newDirectoryinfo) , and when I used file.fullname it generate an exption  (Can not cast a "system.string" type object to type 'system.io.fileinfo')

Comment: (newDirectoryinfo) line should be: DirectoryInfo[] diri_info = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath).GetDirectories(); (add white space between the "new" and "DirectoryInfo".

If your "Process.Start(file.Name)" works without any syntax errors, then my code should work fine. Since both "file.Name" and "file.FullName" return string.

I have edited my answer to include listBox2_Click. You may want to check it again.

This is your full code after being fixed: http://codepad.org/PpIbblj3

Comment: Thank you very much for your help . It works well now  !!

Comment: @monsieur You're welcome. Also, It would be great if you could select this as accepting answer. Thanks a lot!